# show filenames with blank spaces and other symbols in views

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I have this code to save images scraped with nokogiri and mechanize:

```
img_url = agent.page.at(".field-content a")[:href]
root_img_url = URI.join(page_url,img_url).to_s
cover = File.basename(URI.decode(root_img_url))

file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'images', cover), 'wb') { |f|
  f.write(open(root_img_url).read)
}

Book.create(
  :cover => cover
)
```

And in my view I have:

```
<%= image_tag book.cover %>
```

My problem is that some of the filenames end up looking like this **Books'25 b&w_chap 01_.jpg** and my view can't display them.

What can I do to read these files and show in my views?

**UPDATE**

Right now work add downcase and gsub like:

```
cover = File.basename(URI.decode(root_img_url)).downcase.gsub(/[^\w.jpg]/,"")
```

This fix the filename like **books25bw_chap01_.jpg**

With this, the next step is implement File.rename.

Thank for your time.

Comment: When you say "view can't show it", what does that mean? Is your server 404ing on those paths? Anything in the error logs? Have you checked the `<img>` element that is produced to make sure it is what you're expecting it to be?

Comment: Hi @muistooshort, the url of the images is: http://localhost:3000/assets/Book'25%20#02%20Cover%20D_0.jpg but the error apears when i open in a new tab is: No route matches [GET] "/assets/Book'25%20" i thing is the "#" the problem to read it.

Comment: What does the route look like? Routes make certain assumptions about the format of the incoming URLs by default.

Comment: routes.rb only have: resources :books and root :to => 'books#index'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be two causes of this problems:

1. You just have problems with file name format ( with a Sring ). 
   You can play with some String class methods and change file_name to needed format. 
   Or it may be problem with \' symbol.
2. Problems with encoding. Use UTF-8 and you'll not have a problems with encoding.

Correct file's name:

- ENG letters
- no spaces
- no evil symbols like \', \", \: and similar.

Right way is to rename "Books'25 b&w_chap 01_.jpg" to smth like "books_25_b_w_chap_01.jpg", 
when user upload picture on server or after picture are parsed. Or give picture some logical human-understandable name.